# Two relationships to the same table in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I build an application with Laravel which is new for me and got stuck at the model definition.
I have two tables USERS and ACTIONS. 

1) A User can create an "action" or many actions.
2) A user can also be a member of an action that was created by another user.

So if i'm not wrong , the first relation is ONE-TO-MANY relationship ( A user can create many actions, and one action can only be created by one user )
and the second is many to many ( many users can be member of many actions )

I don't know if laravel allow this, or maybe i'm missing something

Thanks to all of you

Comment: Yes, you can do that with [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to have multiple relations between the same tables.

The following relation definitions should work for you:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function actions_created() {
    return $this->hasMany(Action::class, 'creator_id');
  }

  public function actions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class);
  }
}

class Action extends Model {
  public function creator() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
}
```

Make sure you have **action_user** table in place to store the many-to-many relation between users and actions. It should have 3 columns: id, user_id and action_id.

Comment: @Devops could you then mark the question as answered?

Comment: How can i do that ?